# Outlook 2013 keeps asking for credentials when adding new account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, credentials

I wanted to add an IMAP account to Office Outlook 2013 (university account) and when "Testing the account" (sending a test email) the programme keeps asking me for my credentials. No matter if I check the "remember password" box.

[image: The problem]

The above pop-up box keeps re-appearing.

Note that this is a new account in Outlook. So it is not the case that it is an account that I was already using in Outlook and that's gone haywire now. My older accounts in Outlook all work fine. (IMAP as well as POP3)

Comment: Have you reset the password to the account and tried a new set of credentials? What output does outlook give you when trying to test the account (errors - does anything succeed?). This would usually, as I assume you know, would just indicate you've simply entered something wrong.

Comment: @Pretzel I have tested this numerous times, re-installed Outlook, tried changing my password - but nothing works. GMail and Hotmail just work. Don't understand what the problem is. (My credentials *are* correct.)

Comment: Have you checked to see that the mail server you are trying to connect to allows for IMAP? Sometimes they have it disabled or only allow POP3. Also, I would change "imaps" to "imap".

Comment: @Pretzel I have checked this as well. imaps is imap over an SSL connection, it is correct as well.

Comment: Ah, you're using SSL, my bad. Hmm..

Comment: Can you try different mail client and see if you can reproduce issue? Have you contacted your university's IT support. They may be aware of such problems

Comment: @tumchaaditya I have. A similar problem occurs on Windows Phone and Windows 8.1's Mail app. University is trying to help, but to no avail so far.

Comment: try testing with something that is not of microsoft, they might do something different www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/‎

Comment: may be you can try TLS or unencrypted setting for outgoing email and SSL for incoming..

Comment: For anyone still struggling with this, create an app-specific password for outlook. See here for instructions: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, the solution arose when contacting the ICT helpdesk. Apparently, something had gone wrong with password storages or what-not. Changing/resetting the password fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, I fixed it by removing the "Generic Credentials"

You can do this by going here: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

Then delete all the items listed under "Generic Credentials" by pressing the down arrow off to the right, then "Remove from Vault" starting from the top most crednetial.

Then press "ok" in the password prompt and you should be all set

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Access for less secure apps" 
This should work. I tried. 
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with outlook 2010. Like tumchaaditya said try different security settings. Also check the ssl port you are using 143 if ssl/tls is disabled and 993 if it´s enabled.

If your university got webmail for that account as well you may verify that you´re able to login with the same credentials via webmail.

Comment: Did both of those things. Didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my GMail account ... no real error message. Click cancel and try to set your password in the account dialog, there I got a really useful message why my password wasn't working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "more settings" and set correct (non standard, 443 - normally used for https) port for outgoing mail (SMTP), as described [here](https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/services/email)? 
I guess that on standard port (465) there is SMTPS service for staff with another set of logins/passwords.

Comment: I did try so, didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and went to the following site:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

There I saw that google was blocking the sign in request.  After Allowing it worked.

Comment: How do Google security settings help with an Outlook problem?

Comment: @MonicaCellio you can use Google accounts (Gmail) with Outlook, and they can have authentication issues (see [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/668622/#comment1824344_668622))

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The question didn't mention using Google and I didn't make the connection.  Is this answer Google-specific?  If so, should it say so?